# apt-get not working with iptables

Tags: iptables, linux-networking, apt, ubuntu-16.04

I installed iptables and configured to my needs. The problem is that apt-get is not working anymore. Here are my Iptables (`iptables -L -n`):

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 80,443
ACCEPT     tcp  --  192.168.178.0/24     0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 20,21,22
ACCEPT     tcp  --  192.168.178.0/24     0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 53,137,138,139,445
DROP       all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 53,80,443 state NEW,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:53 state NEW,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            192.168.178.0/24     multiport sports 20,21,22,53,137,138,139,445
```

And e.g. `sudo apt-get install git` gets stuck here:

```
admin@nibbler:~$ sudo apt-get install git
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  git-man liberror-perl
Suggested packages:
  git-daemon-run | git-daemon-sysvinit git-doc git-el git-email git-gui gitk gitweb git-arch git-cvs git-mediawiki git-svn
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  git git-man liberror-perl
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 3.760 kB of archives.
After this operation, 25,6 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Ign:1 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main i386 liberror-perl all 0.17-1.2
0% [Connecting to de.archive.ubuntu.com]
```

I read several threads here but did not found the solution. Can someone help me out here? I don't see my error.

I changed the OUTPUT chain to

```
Chain OUTPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 53,80,443 state NEW,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:53 state NEW,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            192.168.178.0/24     multiport sports 20,21,22,53,137,138,139,445
```

I added logging to the OUTPUT,INPUT and FORWARD Chain and it gives me this:

```
Apr 11 10:40:01 nibbler kernel: [ 1052.948383] IN=lo OUT= MAC=00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:08:00 SRC=127.0.0.1 DST=127.0.1.1 LEN=70 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=64463 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=54652 DPT=53 LEN=50 
Apr 11 10:40:01 nibbler kernel: [ 1052.948407] IN=lo OUT= MAC=00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:08:00 SRC=127.0.0.1 DST=127.0.1.1 LEN=70 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=64464 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=54652 DPT=53 LEN=50 
Apr 11 10:40:06 nibbler kernel: [ 1057.953476] IN=lo OUT= MAC=00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:08:00 SRC=127.0.0.1 DST=127.0.1.1 LEN=70 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=106 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=54652 DPT=53 LEN=50 
Apr 11 10:40:06 nibbler kernel: [ 1057.953499] IN=lo OUT= MAC=00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:08:00 SRC=127.0.0.1 DST=127.0.1.1 LEN=70 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=107 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=54652 DPT=53 LEN=50 
Apr 11 10:40:08 nibbler kernel: [ 1060.196071] IN=enp2s0 OUT= MAC=ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ac:bc:32:b7:0b:8f:08:00 SRC=192.168.178.20 DST=255.255.255.255 LEN=261 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=9332 PROTO=UDP SPT=17500 DPT=17500 LEN=241 
Apr 11 10:40:08 nibbler kernel: [ 1060.196655] IN=enp2s0 OUT= MAC=ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ac:bc:32:b7:0b:8f:08:00 SRC=192.168.178.20 DST=192.168.178.255 LEN=261 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=16345 PROTO=UDP SPT=17500 DPT=17500 LEN=241 
Apr 11 10:40:08 nibbler kernel: [ 1060.239479] IN=enp2s0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:fb:ac:bc:32:c2:61:c1:08:00 SRC=192.168.178.22 DST=224.0.0.251 LEN=68 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=14994 PROTO=UDP SPT=5353 DPT=5353 LEN=48 
Apr 11 10:40:08 nibbler kernel: [ 1060.240904] IN=enp2s0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:fb:ac:bc:32:c2:61:c1:08:00 SRC=192.168.178.22 DST=224.0.0.251 LEN=68 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=14995 PROTO=UDP SPT=5353 DPT=5353 LEN=48 
Apr 11 10:40:09 nibbler kernel: [ 1061.243128] IN=enp2s0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:fb:ac:bc:32:c2:61:c1:08:00 SRC=192.168.178.22 DST=224.0.0.251 LEN=68 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=14996 PROTO=UDP SPT=5353 DPT=5353 LEN=48 
Apr 11 10:40:11 nibbler kernel: [ 1062.958890] IN=lo OUT= MAC=00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:08:00 SRC=127.0.0.1 DST=127.0.1.1 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=930 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=39987 DPT=53 LEN=40 
Apr 11 10:40:11 nibbler kernel: [ 1062.958913] IN=lo OUT= MAC=00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:08:00 SRC=127.0.0.1 DST=127.0.1.1 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=931 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=39987 DPT=53 LEN=40 
Apr 11 10:40:11 nibbler kernel: [ 1063.242960] IN=enp2s0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:fb:ac:bc:32:c2:61:c1:08:00 SRC=192.168.178.22 DST=224.0.0.251 LEN=68 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=14997 PROTO=UDP SPT=5353 DPT=5353 LEN=48 
Apr 11 10:40:12 nibbler kernel: [ 1063.947249] IN=enp2s0 OUT= MAC=ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ac:bc:32:b7:0b:8f:08:00 SRC=192.168.178.20 DST=192.168.178.255 LEN=72 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=57187 PROTO=UDP SPT=57621 DPT=57621 LEN=52 
Apr 11 10:40:13 nibbler kernel: [ 1065.017788] IN=enp2s0 OUT= MAC=ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:10:40:f3:82:01:fe:08:00 SRC=192.168.178.26 DST=255.255.255.255 LEN=403 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=747 PROTO=UDP SPT=17500 DPT=17500 LEN=383 
Apr 11 10:40:13 nibbler kernel: [ 1065.017886] IN=enp2s0 OUT= MAC=ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:10:40:f3:82:01:fe:08:00 SRC=192.168.178.26 DST=192.168.178.255 LEN=403 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=39400 PROTO=UDP SPT=17500 DPT=17500 LEN=383 
Apr 11 10:40:15 nibbler kernel: [ 1067.431341] IN=lo OUT= MAC=00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:08:00 SRC=127.0.0.1 DST=127.0.1.1 LEN=78 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=1189 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=44968 DPT=53 LEN=58 
Apr 11 10:40:16 nibbler kernel: [ 1067.963986] IN=lo OUT= MAC=00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:08:00 SRC=127.0.0.1 DST=127.0.1.1 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=1221 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=39987 DPT=53 LEN=40 
Apr 11 10:40:16 nibbler kernel: [ 1067.964022] IN=lo OUT= MAC=00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:08:00 SRC=127.0.0.1 DST=127.0.1.1 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=1222 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=39987 DPT=53 LEN=40 
Apr 11 10:40:17 nibbler kernel: [ 1068.610989] IN=enp2s0 OUT= MAC=ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ac:bc:32:c2:83:61:08:00 SRC=192.168.178.25 DST=255.255.255.255 LEN=215 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=49624 PROTO=UDP SPT=17500 DPT=17500 LEN=195 
Apr 11 10:40:17 nibbler kernel: [ 1068.611063] IN=enp2s0 OUT= MAC=ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ac:bc:32:c2:83:61:08:00 SRC=192.168.178.25 DST=192.168.178.255 LEN=215 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=35073 PROTO=UDP SPT=17500 DPT=17500 LEN=195 
Apr 11 10:40:20 nibbler kernel: [ 1072.436408] IN=lo OUT= MAC=00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:08:00 SRC=127.0.0.1 DST=127.0.1.1 LEN=78 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=1890 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=44968 DPT=53 LEN=58 
Apr 11 10:40:21 nibbler kernel: [ 1072.969138] IN=lo OUT= MAC=00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:08:00 SRC=127.0.0.1 DST=127.0.1.1 LEN=70 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=1949 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=52381 DPT=53 LEN=50 
Apr 11 10:40:21 nibbler kernel: [ 1072.969160] IN=lo OUT= MAC=00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:08:00 SRC=127.0.0.1 DST=127.0.1.1 LEN=70 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=1950 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=52381 DPT=53 LEN=50 
Apr 11 10:40:26 nibbler kernel: [ 1077.441470] IN=lo OUT= MAC=00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:08:00 SRC=127.0.0.1 DST=127.0.1.1 LEN=78 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=2666 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=44968 DPT=53 LEN=58 
Apr 11 10:40:26 nibbler kernel: [ 1077.974220] IN=lo OUT= MAC=00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:08:00 SRC=127.0.0.1 DST=127.0.1.1 LEN=70 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=2722 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=52381 DPT=53 LEN=50 
Apr 11 10:40:26 nibbler kernel: [ 1077.974242] IN=lo OUT= MAC=00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:08:00 SRC=127.0.0.1 DST=127.0.1.1 LEN=70 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=2723 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=52381 DPT=53 LEN=50
```

not sure what I should read out of this..

Comment: how about logging dropped packages with the `-j LOG` chain. Problem is in your `OUTPUT` chain.

Comment: I did added log and edited the thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your logs indicate that you are blocking DNS traffic.

```
Apr 11 10:40:21 nibbler kernel: [ 1072.969160] IN=lo OUT= MAC=00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:08:00 SRC=127.0.0.1 DST=127.0.1.1 LEN=70 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=1950 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=52381 DPT=53 LEN=50 
Apr 11 10:40:26 nibbler kernel: [ 1077.441470] IN=lo OUT= MAC=00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:08:00 SRC=127.0.0.1 DST=127.0.1.1 LEN=78 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=2666 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=44968 DPT=53 LEN=58 
Apr 11 10:40:26 nibbler kernel: [ 1077.974220] IN=lo OUT= MAC=00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:08:00 SRC=127.0.0.1 DST=127.0.1.1 LEN=70 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=2722 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=52381 DPT=53 LEN=50 
Apr 11 10:40:26 nibbler kernel: [ 1077.974242] IN=lo OUT= MAC=00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:08:00 SRC=127.0.0.1 DST=127.0.1.1 LEN=70 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=2723 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=52381 DPT=53 LEN=50
```

Maybe you have a [dnsmasq or unbound recursive resolver to which you are directing your DNS queries](https://askubuntu.com/questions/627899/nameserver-127-0-1-1-in-resolv-conf-wont-go-away)?

Either allow traffic on your loopback interfaces

```
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
```

Or in your INPUT chain, allow the DNS traffic between `SRC=127.0.0.1` and `DST=127.0.1.1`

Comment: Nice that just did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

`apt-get` needs `dns` and `http` - both present in your OUTPUT chain. I think you need to add `ESTABLISHED` to the connection state type, because now you have only `NEW`.

Comment: I changed it to `Chain OUTPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 53,80,443 state NEW,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:53 state NEW,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            192.168.178.0/24     multiport sports 20,21,22,53,137,138,139,445` but it is not working..

Answer (score 0):

Check that ip_conntrack module is loaded in the kernel to enable ESTABLISHED match.

Comment: How do I do this?

Comment: `lsmod | grep conntrack`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using RAW table on iptables. This should give you (for any matching packet) information for each rule this packet passes through.